# Can't get message sent by a client over TCP

Tags: c, linux, sockets, netcat

I wrote a client in C\C++ and sent a message to my local machine which is listening using `nc -l -p 6666`.
After sending the message, nothing was caught with `nc` on my local host.

I suppose the problem is in my code but I am not sure what line.

Why I didn't receive any message with `nc` ?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  //http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

  int sockfd, portno, n;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  struct hostent *server;
  const char ip[] = "127.0.0.1";
  char buffer[256];

  portno = atoi("6666");
  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sockfd < 0) {
    error("ERROR opening socket");
  }
/*
  server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

  if (server == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
      exit(0);
  }

  bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
       (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
        server->h_length);
*/
  inet_aton(ip, &serv_addr.sin_addr);

  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
  if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){ 
      error("ERROR connecting");
  }

  printf("Please enter the message: ");
  bzero(buffer,256);
  fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
   n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    close(sockfd);
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: `sin_family` is not set, that part is commented out.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik write it as answer and I will mark it and we will close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three parts to a `sockaddr_in`:

- Host
  You set this with `inet_aton` (assuming the call succeeded; best add some error checking!)
- Port
  You set this with `serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);`
- Family
  Should be `AF_INET` in your case but, oops, you commented this out!

Everything else looks fine.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem